# What to call someone who takes photos?

Tags: single-word-requests

What to call someone who takes photos? like landscape photos.
After what word should I mention the name? (e.g. XXX: Micheal).
Should it be 'Author' or 'Artist' or 'Photographer'? What is the best word?

Comment: The person *might* call themselves an "artist" if they take highly abstract pictures or use photography as a "medium" for constructed art.  But so long as it's ordinary photographs of people, places, things then they're a "photographer".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure photographer is a perfectly acceptable term. I think anything else would be confusing.

Comment: yes. like in this page: http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:TeslinRiverYukon.jpg    wikimedia uses author. why?

Comment: Wikimedia seems to be using one size fits all for text or photos.  If you use anything other than photographer you run of the risk of confusion.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Nicole The answer is 'photographer'. right?

Comment: Asking the OP questions about the post should be done in a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I didn't have the rep to do that. I'll edit out the question though, as you are correct.